# MODE_PRIVATE in Broacast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, mode

I have defined a function in a class called Receiver that extends the Broadcast Receiver. 
The code of the function is like this:

```
public List<DatabaseRow> ToUpload()
           { 
             sampleDB =  openOrCreateDatabase(TABLE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
             // sampleDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
         Create_Database();
         List<DatabaseRow> list;
         list=Get_Raw("uploaded","no");
         Log.v("TEST", "Size: "+ list.size() );
         int tot = list.size();
    //   return list;
          for (int i=0; i < tot; i++)
           { Log.v("Video id: "+ list.get(i).id, "Video_path: "+ list.get(i).video_path);
           }
           return list;
         // list.get(0).video_path
        // Log.v("TEST", "Size: "+ list.get(0).title);


           }
```

It estract some rows of a database. In Eclipse I get  an error MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable. I have tried to define the same function in an activity and it works. What' s the problem in the Broadcast Receiver and what I have to do to fix it. 
I have already imported Context.

Answer (score 4):

[`MODE_PRIVATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) is an integer declared in the `Context` class. The activity class inherit from `Context` which makes `MODE_PRIVATE` directly accessible from every activity.

`BroadcastReceiver` does *not* inherit from `Context` and `MODE_PRIVATE` is therefore not directly accessible.

Since it is `public static` you can access it like this:

```
Context.MODE_PRIVATE
```

Comment: If I try to insert Context.MODE_PRIVATE like this:
    sampleDB = openOrCreateDatabase(TABLE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
The error on MODE_PRIVATE disappear but I get an error on the function saying:
The method openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, null) is undefined for the type Receiver.

Comment: @user2312945 It is the same problem. BroadcastReceiver does not contain a method called `openOrCreateDatabase`. It is declared in `Context`. You need a reference to your context to call that method. Such a reference is eg. provided in the `onReceive` method of your receiver.

Comment: So what I should do in practice?

Comment: @user2312945 You should get a reference to your `Context` so you can write `context.openOrCreateDatabase(..)`. In the `onReceive` method the context is given as a parameter. If possible, use that one and pass it to your `ToUpload` method.